# Highlighting an area of a map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip, georeferencing

I would like to have a borderline around a subset South-South(SS) part of the map (Map 1) (More like highlighting the subset part).

[image]

I tried to clip a vector of the subset (map 2) to the entire map, but that did not work.

[image]

Comment: I am using QGIS, raster data.

Comment: What is the data in the second screenshot? Is that raster or vector?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Vector --> Geometry Tools --> "Polygons to Line" to get the boundary of this polygon.

Comment: Can't see how that would work though as the OP states in comment they have raster data

Comment: Yes, exactly i have a raster file not polygon

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to manipulate the values of the Raster. Change all Colors you do not need to "no data". You can do this with Raster Calculator.
2. Now you can extract just the area which has Data in it. You can use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447754/better-workflow-for-extracting-boundary-of-raster-in-qgis) solution for this step.