# Better workflow for extracting boundary of raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, performance, pixel

I have got a raster (*.tif*) which has areas with "no data". I want to extract just the area where i have data.

I can do this with `gdal:polygonize` (1) and `native:dissolve` (2).

But especially the first step needs a long time to build all the small polygons.

Does anybody know a faster workflow for this?

Comment: QGIS and GDAL miss a native tool for that purpose. However, there is an open enhancement ticket about that https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/6264. You can make polygonizing faster by creating an image that has only two classes, Data and NoData. For example nearblack can do it https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428556

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following workflow is much faster:

1. Raster Calculator: `"LAYERNAME@1" = "LAYERNAME@1"`
2. gdal:polygonize